# Loop through array in PHP, decode JSON found in files of the same name as the values and assign the decoded JSON to properties

Tags: php, arrays, json, properties, foreach

I'm sorry about the complicated title - it's hard to explain my situation.

This is json/Egg.json:

```
{"1":{"name":"Egg"}}
```

This is index.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class Test {

    public $arrEgg;
    public $arrTypes = array("Egg");

    public function __construct() {
        foreach($this->arrTypes as $strType) {
            if(file_exists("json/$strType.json"))
                $this->{'arr' . $strType} = json_decode(file_get_contents("json/$strType.json"), true);
            else
                echo "File json/$strType.json not found!";
         }
     }
 }

$test = new Test();
echo $test->arrEgg[1]['name']; // I've also tried $test->arrEgg['1']['name']
```

When I run index.php, there is no output.
This is what I want it to output:

```
Egg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

class Test {

    public $arrEgg;
    public $arrTypes = array("Egg");

    public function __construct() {
        foreach($this->arrTypes as $strType) {
            if(file_exists("json/$strType.json"))
                $this->{'arr' .$strType} = json_decode(file_get_contents("json/$strType.json"), true);
            else
                echo "File json/$strType.json not found!";
         }
     }
 }

$test = new Test();
echo $test->arrEgg[0][1]['name'];
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/dlVhRGl5): Egg

Since you want to put data in the `$arrEgg` property, you'll want to append the `$strType`, such as `$this->{'arr' .$strType}`. NOT with `$this->arr{$strType}`.

Your JSON is nested, so you'll still need to access it via `[0][1]['name']`, unless you change your JSON to be: `{"1":{"name":"Test"}}`.

Comment: Removed the square brackets now so I can use `$test->arrEgg[1]['name']`. Output hasn't changed.

Comment: Make sure you're using `$this->{'arr' .$strType}`, it works fine [here](http://codepad.org/Yg9LupCi).

Comment: Works 100% on my side. I created a folder called `json` and placed a file called `Egg.json` and inside `{"1":{"name":"Egg"}}`. Then I copied the code from the question, and ran it. The output was `Egg`. Please check `Egg.json`, the code you are running.

Comment: Oh wow. This isn't the first time this is happened; identical code working for everyone but me.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `file_get_contents(...)` with `'{"1":{"name":"Test"}}'`?

Comment: Oops. I ran it without `file_get_contents` for some reason - just `json_decode("json/$strType.json", true)` instead of `json_decode(file_get_contents("json/$strType.json"), true)`. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You would parse it like that:

**PHP**

```
$json = '[{"1":{"name":"Egg"}}]';
$data =  json_decode($json);
echo $data[0]->{"1"}->{"name"};
```

**Output:**

> egg

<kbd>[DEMO](https://eval.in/107584)</kbd>